# A mesh i export get other colours

Tags: mesh, export

When I export a mesh and open the mesh in another software, it has other colours then in render. Parts of the mesh have moved.

My render settings is workbench and attribute. I export the mesh to a FBX and Collada.

How do I export the mesh as it look in Blender solid view? I drawn colour in solid view with vertex paint. I am not going to now draw colour in material view and rendered view. It doesn't export with those colours. Solid view is the main view to see a mesh.

I created the mesh to export it the 3D animation software Akeytsu. Akeytsu imports Collada and FBX files. I need to know straight how to export the mesh with right colours. Other information doesn't tell me how.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that in your other software you want to see your object as you see it in Solid mode? Solid mode is only made to see a grey scale view of your object

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

I am new user to Blender.
Coming from other software and exporting objects I might get similar behaviour. It might be sometimes down to normals not transferring properly, UVs or deformers not being baked. I would always look online to track down any settings to change in the import or export preferences. Different software's have different axis's which you might have to switch so the native software recognises things.
You might also have to use a certain version of say FBX to work and even then some native programs do not lets say code these export /import options very well because they want you to use their native format.